# Vim, vimux, tmux, and clearing a pane of scrollback buffer

Tags: vim, tmux

**UPDATE:** I've been playing around with this more, and it seems like tmux's `clear-history` command might be broken.

If I have two panes open at `0.0` and `0.1`, and I type in 18 commands in `0.1` then (in `0.0`) run

```
tmux send-keys -t 0.1 q C-u "clear; tmux clear-history" C-m
```

... then switch to pane `0.1` and enter copy mode and scroll up, the scrollbuffer is not cleared.

However, if I run `clear; tmux clear-history` directly from `0.1`, then the scrollbuffer is cleared correctly.

I'm running tmux 1.6. Any thoughts on this behavior?

---

I'm using [vimux](https://github.com/benmills/vimux) to send tests to a tmux pane, prefixing my test commands with

```
call RunVimTmuxCommand("clear; ruby -Itest /spec/some_spec.rb")
```

... but since MiniTest is giving me some pretty long stack traces on some failures, I've taken to entering in copy mode on the vimux pane and searching for `ERROR` with `/`, which works quite well.

The only problem is that the pane preserves the scrollback history, so that I will find failures for tests that I know I've fixed (since I'm searching through history).

I tried amending the above to

```
call RunVimTmuxCommand("clear; tmux clear-history; ruby -Itest /spec/some_spec.rb")
```

But that doesn't seem to work when sent from vimux. If I run the exact same command manually (as in I switch to the vimux pane and run it myself), it works fine.

I'm assuming this is something to do with how vimux sends commands to the pane, but I'm at a loss as to how to fix it. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote in to the author of vimux and he's fixed it already; awesome!

https://github.com/benmills/vimux/issues/26